# replacing string with numeric character in a column through function in R

Tags: r, string, function, numeric

I have been trying to write a function in R that can replace strings in particular column by numerals. Following is my example:

```
d <- data.frame(A = c("D",1,2,3,"D",1,2,"B","D",3,5),
                  B = c(7,8,9,4,5,8,9,1,6,7,8))
func <- function(dat,rep_val_col,rep_val_col_change,new_val)
{
  dat[dat[,rep_val_col] == rep_val_col_change[1],],rep_val_col] = new_val[1]
  dat[dat[,rep_val_col] == rep_val_col_change[2],],rep_val_col] = new_val[2]
}

func(d,"A",c("D","B"),new_val = c(9,10))
```

I want to replace "D" and "B" in column A by 9 and 10 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
levels(d$A)[levels(d$A) %in% c("B", "D")] <- c(9, 10)
d$A <- as.numeric(as.character(d$A))
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked I have modified it for function and it worked perfectly. `code` func <- function(dat,rep_val_col,rep_val_col_change,new_val)
{
  
  levels(dat[,rep_val_col])[levels(dat[,rep_val_col]) %in% rep_val_col_change] <- new_val
  dat[,rep_val_col] <- as.numeric(as.character(dat[,rep_val_col]))
  return(dat)
}

func(d,"A",c("D","B"),new_val = c(9,10)) `code`

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
     mutate(A = case_when(A =="D" ~"9",
                          A=="B" ~ "10",
                         TRUE ~as.character(A)), 
           A = as.integer(A))    #    A B
#1   9 7
#2   1 8
#3   2 9
#4   3 4
#5   9 5
#6   1 8
#7   2 9
#8  10 1
#9   9 6
#10  3 7
#11  5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `ifelse()`:

```
d$A <- with(d, ifelse(A == "D", 9, ifelse(A == "B", 10, A)))

> d
    A B
1   9 7
2   1 8
3   2 9
4   3 4
5   9 5
6   1 8
7   2 9
8  10 1
9   9 6
10  3 7
11  4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a factor variable you can change the levels of this factor via

```
 func <- function(dat,rep_val_col,rep_val_col_change,new_val)
 {
    levels(dat[,rep_val_col])[levels(dat[,rep_val_col]) == rep_val_col_change[1]] <- new_val[1]
    levels(dat[,rep_val_col])[levels(dat[,rep_val_col]) == rep_val_col_change[2]] <- new_val[2]
    return(dat)
 }

 func(d,"A",c("D","B"),new_val = c(9,10))
```

Comment: This one only add NAs at places of D and B.

Comment: Really? It seems to work fine for me though. I get [1] 9  1  2  3  9  1  2  10 9  3  5 with Levels: 1 2 3 5 10 9 for column A.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for something in general but you can do a simple replacement using

```
d$A <- gsub("D", 9, d$A)
d$A <- gsub("B", 10, d$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that having a mixture of strings and numerical values in a column will autmatically convert the whole column to a `factor` (or `character` in some cases).

In this case, however, having a `factor` is actually useful as a `factor` keeps track of unique values as `levels` that we can change using `match` and `replace`.

First, check the levels of `d$A`:

```
levels(d$A)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "5" "B" "D"
```

We can then find the indexes of "B" and "D" using `match`:

```
match(c('D','B'), levels(d$A))
[1] 6 5
```

And replace them using `replace`:

```
replace(levels(d$A), match(c('D','B'), levels(d$A)), c(9, 10))
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "5"  "10" "9"
```

Note that the levels are still of type `character`. Save the new levels and convert the `d$A` to numeric:

```
levels(d$A) <- replace(levels(d$A), match(c('D','B'), levels(d$A)), c(9, 10))
d$A <- as.numeric(as.character(d$A))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It also explains Adam's answer